# How can you get streamed updates from a Blutooth LE device using Flutter [Flutter blue]?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm developing an app for a custom peice of bluetooth hardware.
The spec for the device has a number of commands which can be sent to the device, via a specific Bluetooth Characteristic.

we are currently using this version of Flutter Blue; `flutter_blue:^0.7.2`

So far we have it discovering the device, connecting, and discovering the correct services and characteristics.

We also have it sending commands and receving the expected responses.

This works by listing on the correct chartacteristic like so;

```
    await notify.setNotifyValue(true);
    notify.value.listen((event) {
        _handleEvent(event);
    });
```

and then sending the commnads like so;

```
    await recv.write(command, withoutResponse: true);
```

(where the command is a List representing the payload bytes).

The problem comes in where a response includes more than one packet.
In this case the inital packet is received but the following expected packets do not arrive.

On ios it's working slightly better in that the inital packet is 4 times the size of the Android response and includes the expected data, BUT if the data is too big it's not included.

I've attempted to modify the MTU but this dosen't seem to have any effect on the issue.

Any help would be greatly appeciated.

Comment: There is an open issue on github that describes your problem as well: https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/648https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/648 What size did you try for the MTU and how many bytes do want to send?

Comment: @M.Kotzjan I did try setting the MTU much higher (2048) and also lower than 20. but it seems like the device or the library will not accept anything higher than 20, since even after setting it higher it's reporting it back as 20

Comment: I think the maximum possible MTU for BLE below 5.0 is 251. Setting the MTU only starts a negotiation with the peripheral and they both agree on a value. Since it is working on iOS I assume your peripheral is capable of such a high MTU. Try setting it to 251 which should allow you to receive notifications with up to 248 bytes. You can always try a BLE scanner app like nRF Connect and see if you receive the correct notification there.

Comment: I just realized that my link to the github issue was messed up: https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/648

Comment: Thank you @M.Kotzjan! I was under the impression that setting a high MTU would make the device go to it's highest, but it seems to ignore it unless ti's valid.
setting it to 251 (in my case) did the trick perfectly!

Comment: Great to hear you got it to work! :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case the issue was totally releated to the MTU setting.

I was under the impression that if you requested to set it too high it would automatically go to it's highest possible value. But looks like that is not the case.

If you are seeing a similar issue try setting the MTU to 251